# regex to find TRACE without newline?

Tags: .net, regex, visual-studio-2012

I need to append `\n` to my TRACE statement in a visual studio 2012 c++ project. That is to replace statements such as `TRACE("test an");` to `TRACE("test an\n");`.

I haved tried regex `(TRACE\(\".*([^\\][^n]))\"` and `$1\\n"`

But there are two  problems.

1) the regex does not match string whose last character is n, but the second-last character is not `\`.

e.g. `TRACE("haha an")` does not match.

2) the replacement string `\\n` does not escape `\\` to `\`, the replaced string would contain two `\`.

Could you help me. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(text, "(TRACE\\(.*(?<!\\\\n))(\"\\))", "$1\\n$2");
```

Need to use "Zero-width negative lookbehind assertion.", see [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/az24scfc.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try regex:

```
(TRACE\(")(.*)("\))
```

with replacement:

```
$1$2\\n$3
```

But this will add `\n` even if `\n` already exists. To fix this you can use regex:

```
(TRACE\(")(.*?)(\\n)*("\))
```

with replacement:

```
$1$2\\n$4
```